# how to fairly select a leader

Tags: discrete-mathematics, soft-question

I recently came across a rather practical problem:

A *large* group (around 30 people) wanted to elect a new leader (someone who is not part of the group) of 4 possible candidates. Each of the candidates can be interviewed by the group once (e.g. for one hour). Each member of the group attends at least 3 of the 4 interviews.

What *fair* ways do you suggest to elect the leader? 
(And if you know, what properties does your choosing system have?)

I see the main problem that the 'best' candidate could be in the interview where the least number of group members attend. (Another problem would be whether the final decision should be made *after* all the interviews (so that each member could make a priority list) or rather that each member should cast his 'vote' (in any form) at each of the interviews.)

PS: In the end the system still needs to be so simple that the group of non-mathematicians will grasp it without hours of lecutres about the topic=)

PPS: I think I should tell what system I suggested: Each member should make a priority list of those candidates who's interview he attended. That means someone who attended all interviews distributes 3,2,1,0 points to the four candidates, thos who only attended in three interviews distributes 2,1,0 points to the three candidates who's interview he attended. The candidate with the most number of points wins. (Do you thinkt that is a good system? Could it be improved? What do you think are it's weaknesses?)

Comment: It's perhaps counterintuitive that one can formulate a few reasonable criteria for fairness so that /no/ voting system satisfies all of them (at least, for contests involving more than two candidates---this is the content of Arrow's Impossibility Theorem. Of course, you may reasonably judge some of these criteria as more important than others, or prefer other criteria altogether, but that's a matter of philosophy and not so much one of mathematics. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow's_impossibility_theorem

Comment: Thank you for the link, I did not know about this. But in the end I am looking for practical suggestions=)

Comment: @Travis I just read some more about it, it looks like there is a huge number of different voting systems that satisfy each one or another criterion.

Comment: The condition *Independence of Irrelevant Alternatives* in Arrow's theorem is very strong, and most election methods used in practice do not satisfy it.

Comment: @flawr In your suggested method, note that there is no difference between distributing 2,1,0,0 points to the four candidates and distributing 3,2,1,1 points instead. What happens is that these voters are not able to punish their worst candidate as much as the other voters.

Comment: @PerManne Ah great point, thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

Experience tells us that this problem is difficult also when all the voters know what all the candidates stand for. There are also different practical solutions in this case, each with different mathematical properties.

For instance, voters can vote on who they think is the best candidate, and the candidate with most votes will be the winner. Or the number of candidates may be reduced by elimination in some way or other, and there will be a runoff between two candidates. If the voters have given full rankings of all the candidates, then the result of the runoff may be computed without holding a new election. *Books* have been written about this problem.

What seems to be the issue here is that not all the voters have full information. To focus on that aspect, let *any* method be given which provides a winner when all voters are able to rank all the candidates. If a voter is only able to rank the candidates $a,b,c$, then replace his or her vote by *four* votes, each with weight $1\over 4$, where the last candidate $d$ is inserted in each of the four possible places. (I.e., the incomplete ranking $abc$ is replaced by the four rankings $abcd$, $abdc$, $adbc$, $dabc$, and each of these is given $1\over 4$ of a vote.) Then use your given method to compute the winner.

The mathematical properties of this method depends on your solution to the case with full information. Once you have decided that, you may start to look for properties preserved under incomplete information. (Example: If the method of election is to disregard the votes and always choose the oldest candidate, then the method suggested here will give the same result also in the case of incomplete information.)

Comment: So I just calculated the example of four candidates $abcd$ and someone who just had the *information* about $abc$ but not $d$. He e.g. gives each of $(a,b,c)$ the priority $(3,2,1)$. Your approach would give the candidate $d$ the 'mean priority' and decrease the 'definiteness' of that voters vote (The final pirority might look like $(a,b,c,d) \equiv (3.75,2.5,1.25,25)$ in contrast to someone who saw all candidates who'd vote $(4,3,2,1)$) - Is that correct?

Comment: Why not allow people the freedom to vote about unkown candidates? Such as: Of the interviews with $a,b,c$, the last two turned out so awful, it is safe to assume that $d$ is better than $b,c$, so my priority is $adbc$ (or perhaps mixed with $dabc$).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That looks like a reasonable thought (I mean in the end the group members *do* communicate and influence each other.) But if everyone could vote, would you decrease the weight of those who only saw three of the four candidates?

Comment: @flawr Assuming the [Borda count](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borda_count) method is used, this would be correct. A voter voting in this way is essentially saying: "I have no idea what to do about $d$, so I put $d$ in the middle and let the others decide where $d$ should end up."

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The natural extension would be to permit any convex combination of any set of votes that you are unable to decide between.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Arrow's impossibility theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow's_impossibility_theorem). If by 'fair' you mean Arrow's fairness criteria, then your question has no answer.

Comment: Well as I said, I do not look for *the one* answer, but rather for suggestions how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in other answers and in comments, there is not one right (or perfect) answer to questions like this--and even if all group members attended all interviews, there still wouldn't be a perfect answer.

Here are a couple of other possibilities based on 'approval voting':

(1) Absolute approval voting: After each interview, each attendee approves the candidate (as acceptable) or disapproves the candidate (as unacceptable).  The winning candidate is the one with the most approval votes.  Too bad for a candidate who has less people attending her/his interview.

(2) Relative approval voting: Same voting as above, but now each candidate's score is the proportion of approval votes.  So for instance if a candidate had 25 interview attendees, of whom 19 approved, that candidate's score would be $0.76$.  High score wins.

Comment: Thank you for showing this techniques! So this system might be not appropriate when the group wants to 'compare' the different candidates, but the relative approval voting somehow equalizes the number of attendees at each interview.

Comment: That was my thought (to even out the number of attendees).  There is a lot of information about approval voting (see for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approval_voting.)  I don't know if 'relative approval voting' has been looked at (it just kind of popped into my head).